# nested "if"/"match" statement in scala: better approach?

Tags: scala, if-statement

I have a series of validation functions that returns an Option[Problem], if any, or None if no validation problems are found.
I would like to write a simple function that calls each validation function, stop and return the first not-None result.

Naturally I can write this method in the "java-style", but I would like to know if a better approach exists.

**EDIT**

This was the original Java solution:

```
validate01(arg);
validate02(arg);
validate03(arg);
...
```

Each method throws an exception in case of problem. I would stay away from the exceptions while I'm writing Scala.

Comment: What do you mean by "better"?  What is "java-style?"

Comment: Can you provide example of such code you want to improve?

Comment: Somebody, add monads to Scala!

Comment: @RobertHarvey "java-style" means the verbose method "if/else if/else if..." (or similar using match)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an example, let's say we want to validate a `String`. Our validation function takes a `String` and a list of validators, which are functions from `String` to `Option[Problem]`. We can implement it in a functional manner like this:

```
def firstProblem(validators: List[String => Option[Problem]], s:String) =
  validators.view.flatMap(_(s)).headOption
```

This creates a new list by applying each validation function to the string and keeping the result only if it is a `Some`. We then take the first element of this List. Because of the call to `view`, the list will be computed only as needed. So as soon as the first Problem is found, no further validators will be called.

Comment: You could aslo write it like this - def firstProblem(validators: List[String => Option[Problem]], s: String) = { var r: Option[Problem] = None; for(v <- validators) r = r.orElse(v(s)); r.get }

Comment: @SpiderPig: You could, but he was asking for a functional solution.

Comment: @KimStebel yes you are right, I'm asking for a functional solution

Answer (score 6):

If you have finite and known at compile time number of validations you may use .orElse on Options:

```
def foo(x: Int): Option[Problem] = ...
def bar(x: Int): Option[Problem] = ...
...
def baz(x: Int): Option[Problem] = ...


foo(1) orElse bar(2) orElse .. baz(n)
```

Comment: You can also use foldLeft to apply orElse to an arbitrary Seq of Validations; something like `vs.foldLeft(Option.empty[Problem]) { (result, validation) => result orElse validation(n) }`

Comment: @GregCampbell: And then you have what my solution does, just more complicated and not lazy.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want--assuming the validation functions take no arguments

```
def firstProblem(fs: (() => Option[Problem])*) = {
  fs.iterator.map(f => f()).find(_.isDefined).flatten
}
```

You'll get an existing `Option[Problem]` if there are any, or `None` if they all succeed.  If you need to pass arguments to the functions, then you need to explain what those arguments are.  For example, you could

```
def firstProblem[A](a: A)(fs: (A => Option[Problem])*) = /* TODO */
```

if you can pass the same argument to all of them.  You would use it like this:

```
firstProblem(myData)(
  validatorA,
  validatorB,
  validatorC,
  validatorD
)
```